# Decompressed stream to stream reader

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, gzip

I get `Stream was not readable` when attempting to return a decompressed stream from the follwoing code.

```
    Using strmReader As New StreamReader(FileOpenRead(strFullFilename))
    ...
    End using
```

When calling the following code:

```
Public Function FileOpenRead(ByVal strFullFilename As String) As Stream

        If File.Exists(strFullFilename) Then

            If Path.GetExtension(strFullFilename) = zipExtension Then
                Return DecompressToStream(strFullFilename)
            Else
                Return File.Open(strFullFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            End If
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

Private Function DecompressToStream(ByVal strFullFilename As String) As Stream

        Dim strmDecompressed As Stream = Nothing

        If File.Exists(strFullFilename) Then
            Using inpFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(strFullFilename)
                Using Decompress As New GZipStream(inpFile, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                    strmDecompressed = New BufferedStream(Decompress)
                End Using
            End Using
        End If

        Return strmDecompressed
    End Function
```

I'm using the 3.5 framework, can anyone help me with the best way to return a decompressed stream?

Comment: I think it is because you are returning an object derived from objects wrapped in a `Using` block. When the `End Using` is hit the stream is closed. You need to keep these open until you have finished reading the stream, then call `.Dispose` on them

Comment: Is the best practice to copy from the GZipStream to a byte buffer and then write to the stream to be returned?